# Why don't the people in Walking Dead just cover themselves in blood?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

*Apologies if this is inappropriate - I'm new to scifi.se,*

In the very first season of The Walking Dead, by covering themselves in blood, they were able to walk among the walkers without being detected.  Alas, it started to rain, afterall this is Atlanta, so they had to run for their lives.

Later, however, when going on a supply run or 'mission,' why don't they plug their noses, check that there aren't any rainclouds, and then douse themselves for the ten to thirty minutes it takes to undertake it?  It's not hard to wash clothes and selves later, or does it have some property that burns or something?

**Why don't they use blood (on sunny days) on them to make a quick dash past the walkers?**

EDIT: I understand there was a question asking something similar, and the response was that there are adverse effects and a disgust over time for wearing the guts of walkers.  An additional edit (40 mins ago) was made to an answer to say that some do.  So if I can edit my question to clarify: **Why won't the main characters in Walking Dead in short-term timeframes, and with plugged noses, choose to cover themselves briefly in blood, instead of risking death/zombification by the walkers, when they go on a dangerous mission?**

Comment: The biggest problem with this idea is that if the person who is covering himself or herself in zombie blood has any injuries - even very minor abrasions, cuts, scratches, etc, and if the blood comes in contact with these injuries, the person will be dead very soon.  Transmission of zombie bodily fluids produces results identical to an actual zombie bite.  If you watch the second episode of season one, *Guts*, you will notice that Rick is careful to say "Don't get any on your skin or in your eyes".  That's why.

Comment: @WadCheber - I understand that.  If that's the answer, then fine, but I can see it being the most viable tool an otherwise healthy survivor (or the same covered in protective clothing with an outer layer of the blood) could have on risky excursions.  Certainly a small risk of infection is less than the risk of being caught, chased and/or ambushed.   If the answer is, "don't think about it: just enjoy the show," then I'm happy to accept that.